# How to wrap hashtag and @username with next Link?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-link, react-link

I am working on an application where users can create posts and can mention other `users` and use the `#hashtag` in the post. Through API call I get the list of post, now the question is how can we wrap hashtags and usernames with `next.js Link` component so that on clicking on these link user can be navigated to different pages without page refresh.

I am able to wrap this with `<a>` tag and render the text with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. But this way my page will get refreshed by clicking on the link I don't want off course this behavior.

Here's my code to format the text with `<a>` tag:

```
export const formatPostText = (text) => {
    let splitText = text.split(' ')
    splitText.forEach((word, index) => {
        if (word[0] === "@") {
            splitText[index] = '<a class="text-cyanBlue" href="/' + word.replace('@', '') + '/in' + '">' + word + '</a>'
        } else if (word[0] === "#") {
            splitText[index] = '<a class="text-cyanBlue" href="hashtag' + '/' + word.replace('#', '') + '">' + word + '</a>'
        }
    })
    return splitText.join(' ')
}
```

I do want the same behavior as LinkedIn and Facebook has done it.

Approach: One way I can think of is to use React.createElement but I doubt this is gonna work.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why would you use string instead of jsx?

Comment: User-created posts would be in string format and are stored as strings in the database. for e.g: "Hello everyone, me and @ritika are going to be married this month #happy, #marriage", through API call I get the list of posts with text, now I want to show the text as is, the only difference will be hashtag and username would be wrapped with next js <Link>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented similar things in a recent project. I hope this might be helpful.

```
export const formatText = (text) => {
    console.log("text", text)
    let content = text.split(/((?:#|@|https?:\/\/[^\s]+)[a-zA-Z]+)/);
    let hashtag;
    let username;
    return content.map((word) => {
        if (word.startsWith("#")) {
            hashtag = word.replace('#', '')
            return <Link href={`/hashtag/${hashtag}`}><a
                className="text-cyanBlue/80 hover:text-cyanBlue">{word}</a></Link>;
        } else if (word.startsWith("@")) {
            username = word.replace('@', '')
            return <Link href={`/profile/${username}`}><a
                className="text-cyanBlue/80 hover:text-cyanBlue">{word}</a></Link>;
        } else if (word.includes("http")) {
            return <a target="_blank" href={word} className="text-cyanBlue/80 hover:text-cyanBlue">{word}</a>
        } else {
            return word;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used spans with colors here to make example clear:
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-http-wnp5xq?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const string =
    "Hello everyone, me and @ritika are going to be married this month #happy, #marriage";

  const getJSX = () => {
    // split with capture
    const parts = string.split(/((?:#|@)[a-zA-Z]+)/).filter((s) => s.length);
    return parts.map((part) => {
      if (part.startsWith("@")) {
        // if part starts with `@` return `Link` in your case
        return <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{part}</span>;
      } else if (part.startsWith("#")) {
        // if part starts with `#` return other `Link`
        return <span style={{ color: "green" }}>{part}</span>;
      } else {
        // just return string as is
        return part;
      }
    });
  };

  return <div className="App">{getJSX()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes we make things complicated unnecessarily LOL. Thanks